# Convert cURL request to Guzzle 6

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics, guzzle6

I'm trying to convert some Google Analytics event tracking code from a cURL request to Guzzlehttp 6. The Guzzle request comes back with 200, but the event is not tracked. The same request gets tracked using cURL. Any ideas?

Working cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            'v=1&t=event&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&cid=' . $cid . '&ec=' . $cat . '&ea=' . urlencode($action) . '&el=' . urlencode($label) . '&uip=' . $uip . '');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

GuzzleHttp:

```
$postData['form_params'] = [
    'v' => '1',
    't' => 'event',
    'tid' => 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x',
    'cid' => $cid,
    'ec' => $cat,
    'ea' => $action,
    'el' => $label,
    'uip' => $uip
];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', $postData);
```

Comment: What is the returning response body?